# Client-Side VBScript application, Incorrect Current Working Directory

Tags: vbscript, cwd

I'm not understanding this behavior. Maybe someone can explain to me why my current working directory is not what I expect.

On my desktop, I have a folder called STKGui:

C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui

Located in that directory are the following files: gui.html, style.css, save.html, load.html  Within STKGui there are also the following directories: Images, Scripts, and SaveData. Scripts contains various .vbs files, including gui.vbs.

I start with gui.html. I click a button which takes me to load.html. load.html uses scripts from Scripts\gui.vbs. One of the functions loads a database, and to do so I provide the location of the database: C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui\SaveData\SaveData.accdb   Of course I want to use a relative file path instead of a fixed path. My initial attempt to load the database failed; it was trying to load from C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\SaveData\SaveData.accdb. So to troubleshoot I printed out the current working directory; much to my chagrin it was C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop

I don't understand why my desktop is my current working directory. Shouldn't it be where the file is running from? I figured it would be either C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui (the location of load.html) OR C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui\Scripts (the location of gui.vbs which contains the function that's trying to load the database/printing debug messages of the current working directory).

Can someone explain why the current working directory is what it is, or better yet tell me how to get what I really want, which is the location of the files executing? (I don't care if it's the main STKGui folder or the scripts folder--as long as it's within the application's directory structure I can work with it!)

---

EDIT (7/14/10 4:02 pm EDT):

Various attempts at printing the current working directory or grabbing files based on what I -thought- was the relative path from my executing script have resulted in my desktop's path instead of the path of the executed script. I stumbled across this link: http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/vbscript-current-directory-or-folder/  but none of the solutions are working for me, as I get run-time errors regarding the Wscript object. So while I don't know if any of the solutions on the aforementioned link will produce different results, if someone can help me get at least one of them working so I can find out that may be a step in the right direction.

One of the solutions, reproduced below:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = ofso.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
```

produces the following error:

Object required: 'Wscript' line: 659 char: 1

with line 659 being:

```
oShell.CurrentDirectory = ofso.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was NOT ideal, but what I ended up doing was parsing the url in my browser to get the directory.

```
guiPath = Mid(location.PathName, 2, len(location.PathName))

Set regExp = New RegExp
regExp.IgnoreCase = False
regExp.Global = True
regExp.Pattern = ".*/"

Set matchCollection = regExp.Execute(guiPath)

Set match = matchCollection(0)

guiPath = match.value

regExp.Pattern = "%20"

guiPath = regExp.Replace(guiPath, " ")

systemsDBPath = guiPath & "SaveData\SaveData.accdb"
```

Like I said, less than ideal. May not even work once I'm working with the application this will be running in. But I couldn't find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

For Server-Side:

You should be using `Server.MapPath()` to get your "working directory". For instance, if you want to get the path to your database file in `C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui\SaveData\SaveData.accdb`, your app root being `C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\STKGui`, you would use `Server.MapPath("SaveData\SaveData.accdb")`.

For Client-Side:

Upon closer examination and digging up some memories, I realized that MapPath is only available from the Server class. Instead, you need to create a file system object like this:

```
''get fs object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
''get actual file using path relative to calling vbs file
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("SaveData\SaveData.accdb")
''get path to the database
set sPathToDatabase = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)
```

In case it helps, here is a great resource for working with the file system in vbScript: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/filesfolders/files/

Comment: This is client-side, not server-side stuff. Strange, I know, but it's for an application that will load this into its interface in an html viewer.

Comment: I tried it without the Server object to see if your solution would still work for client-side:

    Set sCurPath = MapPath("SaveData\SaveData.accdb")
    document.write("sCurPath = " & sCurPath)

is giving me an error: Type mismatch 'MapPath' I've never had this difficulty before when I use Set on a brand new variable! Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the entire error message and verify the line number?

Comment: Type mismatch: 'MapPath' line: 652 char: 2 gui.vbs     line 652 is: Set sCurPath = MapPath("SaveData\SaveData.accdb")        Sorry for the poor formatting, not sure how to format better in comments.

Comment: Ok. Just making sure the mappath line is really the offending line. Gimme a sec and I'll try it out.

Comment: It is still giving me this for my filepath:

C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\SaveData\SaveData.accdb completely ignoring my STKGui directory! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: As a side note, if I change the code to sPathToDatabase = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName("SaveData.accdb"), sPathToDatabase equals C:\Documents and Settings\Lauren\Desktop\SaveData.accdb  --it's just appending whatever I put to my desktop path. I don't understand. :(

Comment: Ok. I believe I've got it now.

Comment: Your code isn't wrong. I believe what you had before was also correct. I think the problem here is that as per your comment ''get actual file using path relative to calling vbs file, you and I are both expecting it to use a path relative to the calling vbs file, but this is not so. For whatever reason, it keeps referring to my desktop no matter what. When I used Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("SaveData\SaveData.accdb"); sPathToDatabase = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile), (; inserted to show line break), it told me the file didn't exist. (It didn't print the full path of the file it was...

Comment: attempting to grab so I just had to guess that it was still trying to grab Desktop\SaveData\SaveData.accdb.) Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("STKGuiI\SaveData\SaveData.accdb");
''get path to the database;
sPathToDatabase = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile); worked. As an experiment, I copied my STKGui folder into another location--My Documents--and tried running the application from there. It still worked but only because I hadn't removed the original folder from the desktop: it was still printing that the location of the database was Desktop\STKGui\SaveData\SaveData.accdb ...

Comment: Crap. I'm at a loss, then. Best of luck to you.

Comment: If you take a look at this: http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/vbscript-current-directory-or-folder/  I'm beginning to think that my current working directory is not the same as the location my script is running from. So I tried the approaches listed on that site to get the directory my script is running from. Problem is, I keep getting a really unhelpful error message that tells me Object Required: Wscript. I have no idea what this error message means, but the code for the first bullet in the list under "Edit:..." throws that error on the very last line.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Byron! I really do appreciate your help. :)